# Retrieve valid values for parameter PaperSize of Set-PrintConfiguration

Tags: powershell, parameters

We're trying to verify valid input for the parameter `PaperSize` of `Set-PrintConfiguration`.

We're trying to create an array with all possible accepted values for the argument:

```
$testCommand = Get-Command Set-PrintConfiguration
$testCommand.Parameters.PaperSize

$testPaperSie = [Microsoft.PowerShell.Cmdletization.GeneratedTypes.PrinterConfiguration.PaperSizeEnum]
$testPaperSie.DeclaredFields.Name
```

This does return a list of options but it also includes a value like `value__` which does not seem to be suggested by `intellisense`. This makes me think the query for valid values is incorrect.

Comment: I think you want to look at the [PaperKind enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.paperkind?view=netframework-4.7.2). `[enum]::GetNames([System.Drawing.Printing.PaperKind])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the possible values from the [PaperKind](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.paperkind?view=netframework-4.7.2) enum, you can do something like this:

```
function Get-Enum {
    param (
        [type]$Type
    )
    if ($Type.BaseType.FullName -ne 'System.Enum') {
        Write-Error "Type '$Type' is not an enum"
    }
    else {
        [enum]::GetNames($Type) | ForEach-Object {
            $exp = "([$Type]::$($_)).value__"
            [PSCustomObject] @{
                'Name'  = $_
                'Value' = Invoke-Expression -Command $exp
            }
        }
    }
}

Get-Enum System.Drawing.Printing.PaperKind
```

On my machine it returns:

> ```
> Name                               Value
> ----                               -----
> Custom                                 0
> Letter                                 1
> LetterSmall                            2
> Tabloid                                3
> Ledger                                 4
> Legal                                  5
> Statement                              6
> Executive                              7
> A3                                     8
> A4                                     9
> A4Small                               10
> A5                                    11
> B4                                    12
> B5                                    13
> Folio                                 14
> Quarto                                15
> Standard10x14                         16
> Standard11x17                         17
> Note                                  18
> Number9Envelope                       19
> Number10Envelope                      20
> Number11Envelope                      21
> Number12Envelope                      22
> Number14Envelope                      23
> CSheet                                24
> DSheet                                25
> ESheet                                26
> DLEnvelope                            27
> C5Envelope                            28
> C3Envelope                            29
> C4Envelope                            30
> C6Envelope                            31
> C65Envelope                           32
> B4Envelope                            33
> B5Envelope                            34
> B6Envelope                            35
> ItalyEnvelope                         36
> MonarchEnvelope                       37
> PersonalEnvelope                      38
> USStandardFanfold                     39
> GermanStandardFanfold                 40
> GermanLegalFanfold                    41
> IsoB4                                 42
> JapanesePostcard                      43
> Standard9x11                          44
> Standard10x11                         45
> Standard15x11                         46
> InviteEnvelope                        47
> LetterExtra                           50
> LegalExtra                            51
> TabloidExtra                          52
> A4Extra                               53
> LetterTransverse                      54
> A4Transverse                          55
> LetterExtraTransverse                 56
> APlus                                 57
> BPlus                                 58
> LetterPlus                            59
> A4Plus                                60
> A5Transverse                          61
> B5Transverse                          62
> A3Extra                               63
> A5Extra                               64
> B5Extra                               65
> A2                                    66
> A3Transverse                          67
> A3ExtraTransverse                     68
> JapaneseDoublePostcard                69
> A6                                    70
> JapaneseEnvelopeKakuNumber2           71
> JapaneseEnvelopeKakuNumber3           72
> JapaneseEnvelopeChouNumber3           73
> JapaneseEnvelopeChouNumber4           74
> LetterRotated                         75
> A3Rotated                             76
> A4Rotated                             77
> A5Rotated                             78
> B4JisRotated                          79
> B5JisRotated                          80
> JapanesePostcardRotated               81
> JapaneseDoublePostcardRotated         82
> A6Rotated                             83
> JapaneseEnvelopeKakuNumber2Rotated    84
> JapaneseEnvelopeKakuNumber3Rotated    85
> JapaneseEnvelopeChouNumber3Rotated    86
> JapaneseEnvelopeChouNumber4Rotated    87
> B6Jis                                 88
> B6JisRotated                          89
> Standard12x11                         90
> JapaneseEnvelopeYouNumber4            91
> JapaneseEnvelopeYouNumber4Rotated     92
> Prc16K                                93
> Prc32K                                94
> Prc32KBig                             95
> PrcEnvelopeNumber1                    96
> PrcEnvelopeNumber2                    97
> PrcEnvelopeNumber3                    98
> PrcEnvelopeNumber4                    99
> PrcEnvelopeNumber5                   100
> PrcEnvelopeNumber6                   101
> PrcEnvelopeNumber7                   102
> PrcEnvelopeNumber8                   103
> PrcEnvelopeNumber9                   104
> PrcEnvelopeNumber10                  105
> Prc16KRotated                        106
> Prc32KRotated                        107
> Prc32KBigRotated                     108
> PrcEnvelopeNumber1Rotated            109
> PrcEnvelopeNumber2Rotated            110
> PrcEnvelopeNumber3Rotated            111
> PrcEnvelopeNumber4Rotated            112
> PrcEnvelopeNumber5Rotated            113
> PrcEnvelopeNumber6Rotated            114
> PrcEnvelopeNumber7Rotated            115
> PrcEnvelopeNumber8Rotated            116
> PrcEnvelopeNumber9Rotated            117
> PrcEnvelopeNumber10Rotated           118
> ```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you Theo, I'm trying to do the same for the `DuplexingMode`. What class would that be? Because the `Duplex` class tells me other values than the `DuplexingMode` argument on the CndLet.

Comment: @DarkLite1 Accodring to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/printmanagement/set-printconfiguration?view=win10-ps) there are only three values possible for `-DuplexingMode`: `OneSided`, `TwoSidedLongEdge`, `TwoSidedShortEdge`.

Comment: Correct, but I was looking for a generic way to find the options for that specific parameter. So I could apply the same logic for other CmdLets and their arguments.

Comment: @DarkLite1 The enum is part of the System.Printing namespace, so you would have to use `Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Printing`. Looking at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.printing.duplexing?view=netframework-4.6.2) you should be able to get it via `System.Printing.Duplexing`, however.. I cannot seem to get that part to work on my Windows 7 Pro machine.. (_Unable to find type [System.Printing.Duplexing]_)

Comment: Jup, I tried that already. And indeed, no luck. But what I was really curious about is if there is `PowerShell` way of finding these values. Through `Get-Comman` I mean without directly addressing the class.